# Enterprise Framework - UWP Vs. Web

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, architecture, platform

Broad, sweeping question here...

Assume you have built an enterprise level framework with some rich client in the .Net (Microsoft) sphere, with a WCF back end. Now, imagine that that enterprise framework's UI technology is being deprecated in favour of UWP.

The choices for a front end replacement basically are: UWP, Web (HTML), or some other rich client technology.

***How would you go about the decision making process?***

I personally lean toward a rich client where the user base is a captive user base. I mean, where the users' IT department is happy to install the necessary runtime environment on the machines, etc. This is usually not a problem with Microsoft technologies, and this won't be a problem in about 10 years when organizations roll out Windows 10.

But, people are telling me these days that web has come a long way. People are telling me that JavaScript frameworks are becoming very sophisticated, and that low level JavaScript for basic data binding and the like is mostly unnecessary.

I have really been turned off by web solutions like ASP in the past, but I do understand that technology has moved forward, and I do understand that Microsoft have been working on ASP.Net v Next which might actually be good?

The question is not so much what would you opt for? But, ***what factors would you take in to account to decide which platform to go for***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to answer this question here because we've had a lot more time to investigate and look at different options. The original question turned out to be a bit of a furphy. Pure UWP and Web are not the only options. There is also a Xamarin Forms as an option which includes UWP, Android, and iOS. As a personal preference, I am leaning toward using Xamarin Forms as a client instead of any other development platform because it supports three OSs out of the box: Windows 10, iOS, and Android.

I believe the answer to the question is: you should only develop a web app if you need to. Does your user base consist of people who will mostly prefer a browser over apps? Are your potential users likely to want to avoid downloading an app? Is your app very simple, and you want people to be able to dive in very quickly? Are you able to get away without access to things like the camera, location and push notifications? If you can answer yes to these things, then I think you should go for HTML 5/JavaScript. If however, your user base is comfortable downloading apps, and you think that your app will require a UI more sophisticated than most browser apps, I'd recommend looking at Xamarin Forms as the preferred option. We've had very good success with Xamarin Forms so far, and the UWP version of our Xamarin Forms app has turned out just as good as our first stab at a UWP app.

Note: I should give Web Assembly (http://webassembly.org/) an honorable mention here. This technology is being considered in all the big tech organisations like Microsoft, Apple, and Google. One day, it may make deployment of native apps in a browser great again.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Very interesting to read the original question and answer and then see what transpired 2 years down the line.

Comment: Thanks. While this is still a largely opinion based answer, I feel the general tide is turning toward native apps rather than HTML/JavaScript apps. I could be completely wrong about that, and the decision of whether to build a web app or native app is still very much dependent on circumstance more than anything else.

Comment: I think it also depends on the tooling that the company is familiar with. A web house will lean towards Cordova/React.Native and a Microsoft C# house towards Xamarin.

Comment: To some extent. I guess the real debate is to be had on whether browser based compiled apps (Cordova/React.Native) are going to be as good a solution as native apps. That's definitely outside the scope of the original question. I don't think that a team should make that called based on what skills they have in the team. That call should be made based on what the enterprise framework's UI requires, and what technology best suits the end result.

Comment: They are never going to be _as_ good. The question is are they good enough. For an internal enterprise app it may be sufficient especially if a web house can re-use a lot of code. I have worked for several companies that tried this. The results were poor. I would always lean towards a Xamarin Forms app.

Answer (score 2):

Opnion based answer here...

In a decision to adopt a particular tech for any project lies in many factors. I can cite two majors for your particular scenario.

1 - Client adoption. It's easy for the customers to use/install it? They need to pay some sort of license? Can it run in all platforms/devices the customer already own?

2 - Market adoption. It's easy for you co-workers to adopt it? It's hard to find/hire experienced/hardened developers? We need to pay some kind of license? Can I trust it ill be a long lived technology?

The answer to your question can be **HTML**.

Not only it is already got a lot of momentum in market, it ill take years to change it even if today someone (big like MS or Google) put some new (better) stuff on the table.

Also if someone on MS marketing dep say next week Universal Windows Platform or WinRT must die it ill die (like Silverlight). So Im not adopting some new technology just because some big player told me to do it.

Yes **web has come a long way** indeed. You can do a lot of amazing things just with JS+HTML+CSS those days. Also the right usage/architecture of it ill allow you to put your app running in PCs, Tablets and Mobiles (at a minimum cost to port between devices) and capable in running in anything can access internet.

I suggest you to catch up and learn a lot about webservices, Json, JS libraries like JQuery, Sammy and some nice stuff like Knockout, SPA, Angular, Node, etc.

**Edit, answer to comments**

To not start a chatty comment I'll respond here. Yes your questions and comments brings interesting questions. To let it readable for posterity both of us can edit answer and question to organize it.

Silverlight. How not love it? In special after strugling with flash. It's a shame MS pulled the plug (die in hell MS CEOs). When MS let it to die I was planning a big web app SL was my first choice. Why I changed my mind? Well 2 years to develop that app and at the end how much browser ill get along supporting it? The SL community is great, the tool is great but browsers can just say, Hey tomorrow there's no guarantee it keep working.

.Net and MS platforms. I'm a .Net developer. I adopted it since beta, first to work with winforms (in a previous life I was a proud Delphi developer). After a while started to work with web. I also worked in classical ASP (bad times) and loved .Net ASP from start.

You can run .Net apps in almost any PC in the planet today. Not exactly true for all mobiles/gadgets. For browsers pure HTML+JS+CSS ill to better because it's lightweight (done right). Also we can move a lot of thing to client side and just let it hit the server only when necessary. .Net apps can do that, sure, but ill never be light as a tailored HTML+JS+CSS.

In fact I believe you can do anything with .Net and you can do amazing things if you got a few good developers in your team. But depending on the project it ill do better (and cheaper) in HTML or PHP or Ruby or Java, etc.

In fact at a previous shop, with both PHP and .Net teams we found (after 1 year study, metrics, lots of projects) small projects are better done in PHP, larger ones in .Net (if I remember a medium project can be 4k to 6k men/hours).

The point here is. You really must read a lot about HTML, CSS, JS, SPA, Angular, etc. Bringing to live a big and shinning web app is challenging today not because what we can do (we can do anything) but how we can do. DDD, MVC, MVVM. Testing framework, etc. Man Node **is** the future (the concept at least).

Web developing really changed in the last years and with it the clients and users expectations. Today no one ill wait for more than 2 secs for a page to load. Everybody wants usability to be at the top of the table from project scratch. You app must be responsive, etc. (not using Dilbertian management buzz words here for the sake of it. Just stating usability is that important today).
And don't forget everyone wants it to be beatifull (from a graphical designer point of view) even if it's a dull B2B supposed to be used only by cave mens.

Even if you stick to a classical .Net app learn about the (many) options, that can bring a new wider perspective.

Comment: I guess the answers to questions 1) in regards to UWC, is yes. It is easy to install (app store), it will require some minimal fee for the app store, and it will work on existing Windows phones which our customers are accustomed to buying.

Comment: 2) It won't be hard to find experienced developers because basically UWC leverages c#, and XAML which are two very familiar technologies to Microsoft developers. But, there are obviously no guarantees that it will be a long lived technology which is the point of this post really. You've hit the nail on the head with Silverlight

Comment: Actually, it raises an interesting question. Silverlight is dead in the water, but our Silverlight app has served us very well. If someone asked me, "knowing what you know now - that Silverlight was going to die, would you have built the app on Silverlight anyway?". And, the answer to that is a clear yes. We've had a good 5 year run on Silverlight, and there is a few more years left in the technology before it gets boo'd out of the marketplace.

Comment: But, it's still better than the alternative which is to use HTML/JavaScript based technologies. I'm not saying that those technologies are inherently bad - but at the time of starting our Silverlight app, many of the problems with the Web had not been worked out. HTML 5 had not been released, ASP was still several versions behind, and basically doing anything for the web with Microsoft technology was painful. But, right now, web has improved a lot. So, I'm right on the borderline of deciding which technology to invest more heavily in.

Comment: The question confronting us right now, is given that web has improved a lot, and at the same time, not knowing anything about the future longevity of the UWP platform, is ASP5 + the frameworks you mentioned a safer bet?

Comment: As a general comment, I really do find that developers are far too dismissive of rich (fat) client technologies. People will call me a luddite for praising Silverlight so much, but I can honestly say that apart from a few quirks that were never ironed out, Silverlight was by far, the best platform I've ever built on, and it allowed us to build a very rich application where the UI is abstracted from the code base, the business logic is also abstracted, as well as the database structure. These things are all configurable with ease. The same could be recreated on UWP.

Comment: Obviously, the same could be recreated with ASP, but the question for me is, how much harder will it be?